# How to change a nav image once it reaches different div elements when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an image in the nav (lets call it pic1), that needs to change to pic2 once I reach the top of my page content div, but when I reach the footer it needs to change back to pic 1 and repeat, so if I scroll back up to page content it will go to pic 2 again, etc.

I tried doing something like the below but can't get it to work, how can I make it work?

```
var scrollContent = $("#content").offset().top;
var scrollHero = $("#hero").offset().top;

var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

if (scrollPos > scrollContent) {
    $(".image-test").css({
        "background-image": "url('')"
    });
}  else if(scrollPos < scrollContent) {
    $(".image-test").css({
        "background-image": "url('')"
    });
```

[Here is my codepen link](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/PoNQqLp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with the jQyery code you are trying to use:

**1.** You are only checking the scroll position on page load - you need to continuously check inside the scroll event:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function( /* handler function */));
```

**2.** You are trying to change the image through CSS, but the image isn't displayed using CSS. Instead you can change the `src` of the `img` element like this:

```
$(".image-test img").attr("src", imgUrl);
```

**3.** You're not checking for the bottom of the page content element (where the replacement image it to be swapped back). You can get it like this:

```
var contentTop = $(".page-content").offset().top;
var contentBottom = contentTop + $(".page-content").outerHeight(true);
```

**4.** You need to check if the scroll is between these positions:

```
if ( ($(this).scrollTop() > contentTop) && ($(this).scrollTop() < contentBottom))
```

For to make this responsive (i.e. so it will work if the screen size is changed after the page is loaded by resizing the window for example) you need to include it inside the scroll event handler also.

**Full Code for Function**

```
// get the URL of the image so we can use it to swap back
defaultImgUrl =  $(".image-test img").attr("src");

// check the scroll position on the scroll event
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  // get the top and bottom positions pf the page content
  var contentTop = $(".page-content").offset().top;
  var contentBottom = contentTop + $(".page-content").outerHeight(true);

  // check if the scroll position is within the page content 
  if (($(this).scrollTop() > contentTop) && ($(this).scrollTop() < contentBottom)) {
    // change the image url
    $(".image-test img").attr("src", "https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-50-2.jpg");
  } else {
    $(".image-test img").attr("src", defaultImgUrl);
  }
  
});
```

**Working Example:**

```js
// get the URL of the image so we can use it to swap back
defaultImgUrl = $(".image-test img").attr("src");

// check the scroll position on the scroll event
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  // get the top and bottom positions pf the page content
  var contentTop = $(".page-content").offset().top;
  var contentBottom = contentTop + $(".page-content").outerHeight(true);

  // check if the scroll position is within the page content 
  if (($(this).scrollTop() > contentTop) && ($(this).scrollTop() < contentBottom)) {
    // change the image url
    $(".image-test img").attr("src", "https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-50-2.jpg");
  } else {
    $(".image-test img").attr("src", defaultImgUrl);
  }

});
```

```css
.section1,
.section2,
.page-content {
  height: 100vh;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: red;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.image-test img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="image-test">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-100-50-5.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Change me to a different picture once I reach the top of page content. Then change me back to the same picture as the one I had in the hero once I reach the footer.</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="section1" id="hero">
  <h1>Hero</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
  <h1>Page Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="section2">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for going into detail and explaining the solution, will now learn for next time. Thank you

Comment: @birdyoung Glad to help! If you understand what it is doing, then it makes it easier for you to adapt to your own code or reuse the function in different projects :)